# How to set Text from another layout without using Shared Preferences or putExtra

Tags: android, android-layout, gettext, settext

I have two textViews in different activity A and B that need to have the same Value. I can not use putExtra because I am not going from Activity A to B. I do not want to use Shared Preferences. I do not want to put then query from a sqlite. Is there a way for me to call for the Text in Activity A when I am on Activity B ?

I am able to get the Layout value of Activity A from Activity B but not the text Value in a textView of Activity A

In Activity B

```
Name1.setText(R.layout.menuview);
```

That will give me the name value of the xml file. I want the value of a this textView inside the xml file.

In Activity A

```
m1a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m1a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why cant u use shared preference?
 
 you can use static variable and keep value in memory.

Comment: The Text in Activity 1 can change. Shared Preferences may lose the value.

Comment: so everytime text gets changes you update the value in shared preference also. in case of static variable also, you will have to do the same thing.

Comment: I tried to                                                 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityA.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
           editor.putString("something", "");
           editor.commit();                                      and retrieving                                       SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityB.this);
textView.setText(pref.getString("something", "NULL")); but it didn't work

Comment: code block is right. what are you putting in shared preference. you are sending blank value in your code. save whatever value you have in text field in activity 1.
how did it not work? I mean what was the error/response/output?

Comment: Sorry.I wrote that too fast, wasn't thinking. I actually had editor.putString("something", "textsomething.getText().toString()");. When I wrote in a test value like editor.putString("something", "testing 123"); The testValue came through but never the actual real value of textsomething.

Comment: everytime you change value of textsomething, you will update sharedpreference. is textsomething textview or edittext?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37406/discussion-between-rachit-and-smulianjulian)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static variable on a helper class.

`public class Helper {
      static String text;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

The way that one activity changes view property directly by reference of another activity isn't good way.
Because activity should reference another one, it is reason of memory leak.

I suggest below ways

1) LocalbroadcastReceiver

If you use this, dependency is gone between the activities. Also you can observe changing in real time. But some codes be added.

2) SharedPreference

It is another alternative methods, but it use disk io and disk space.
If you have to save values permanently, using this way.